# Python RegEx group text before splitter character and after with the whole text?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a CS student and our professor gave us this "example" which I poorly translated, but it's supposed to:

"Get the inner brackets data and strip the associated brackets, then add the rest of the text with a space in between".

`import re
pattern=re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')
res=pattern.search('(Today is a nice and sunny)day!)')
print(res.group())`

I see what's supposed to be the result:

```
(Today is a nice and sunny)
(Today is a nice and sunny day!)
```

But the code only prints the former and I tried messing with res.groups() by enveloping the entire thing in brackets and changing the expression but just couldn't figure out how to make it produce one group in which it stops at the first ) bracket and one in which it ignores it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the Regex is not working that way is because it is not written in a way to use multiple capture groups. To fix this I created two capture groups, one that will capture on the first and a second that will capture the leftover day portion.

```
   import re
   pattern = re.compile(r'(\(.*?\))(.*\))?')
   res = pattern.search('(Today is a nice and sunny)day!)')

   #This will print (Today is a nice and sunny)day!)
   print(res.group())

   #This will print (Today is a nice and sunny)
   print(res.groups()[0])
```

I then had to call `res.group` and `res.groups` separately because `res.group` will return the full match and `res.groups` will return the sub matched groups in a tuple. I then index the return of `res.groups` to obtain the first capture group result.

For info on capture groups in Regex, checkout [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Comment: Without the ")", king.

Either way thanks greatly for your help, based on this I've done the following:

`print(res.group(1).split(')')[0]+res.group(2))`

And it prints the intended (Today is a nice and sunny day!) block, let me know if there's a better way ;)

Comment: print(rez.group(1)[:-1]+rez.group(2))
Already figured I could do this